# Display notice in block editor after wp_insert_post_data hook

Tags: admin, block-editor, validation, notices

I have a custom post type which checks and validates some (custom) meta fields added with it upon publishing. I am using `wp_insert_post_data` for the purpose:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->sconfig= ['post_type'=> 'event', 'slug'=>'events'];
    add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', array($this, 'validate_event_meta'), 99, 2);
    add_filter('post_updated_messages', array($this, 'event_save_update_msg'), 10, 1);
    //add_action('admin_notices', array($this, 'event_save_update_msg'));
}

function validate_event_meta($postData, $postArray)
{
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return $postData;
    }
    if (array_key_exists('post_type', $postData) && $postData['post_type'] === $this->sconfig['post_type']) {
        if (array_key_exists('post_status', $postData) && $postData['post_status'] === 'publish') {
            $valstat = $this->get_meta_posted_vals();
            /*
            $valstat['stat'] is 0 or 1 depending on validation success
            $valstat['log'] has the error message
            */
            if ($valstat['stat'] == 0) {
                $postData['post_status'] = 'draft';
                set_transient(get_current_user_id() . '_event8273_add_notice', 'ERROR: ' . $valstat['log']);
                add_filter('redirect_post_location', array($this, 'alter_event_save_redirect'), 99);
            }
         }
    }
    return $postData;
}

function alter_event_save_redirect($location)
{
    remove_filter('redirect_post_location', __FUNCTION__, 99);
    $location = remove_query_arg('message', $location);
    $location = add_query_arg('message', 99, $location);
    return $location;
}

function event_save_update_msg($messages)
{
    $message = get_transient(get_current_user_id() . '_event8273_add_notice');
    if ($message) {
        delete_transient(get_current_user_id() . '_event8273_add_notice');
        //echo $message;
        //$messages['post'][99] = $message;
        $messages[$this->sconfig['post_type']][99] = $message;
    }
    return $messages;
}
```

Though the validation system is working correctly, I cannot display any notices on the error. Each time the code encounters invalid meta value during 'publish', it reverts the post into 'draft' status and the 'Draft Saved *Preview*' message pops up.

Upon some research, I have found that the [block editor uses javascript to display custom notices](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/notices/#notices-in-the-block-editor). But what I cannot understand is how to call the javascript function (file already enqueued in admin) after the validation from `wp_insert_post_data`.

```
function event_save_alert(errmsg)
{
    ( function ( wp ) {
        wp.data.dispatch( 'core/notices' ).createNotice(
            'error', // Can be one of: success, info, warning, error.
            errmsg, // Text string to display.
            {
                isDismissible: true, // Whether the user can dismiss the notice.
                // Any actions the user can perform.
                actions: [
                    {
                        url: '#',
                        label: 'View post',
                    },
                ],
            }
        );
    } )( window.wp );
}
```

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks for reading this far and giving it a thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what I cannot understand is how to call the javascript function (file
> already enqueued in admin) after the validation from
> `wp_insert_post_data`

You can use the same approach that Gutenberg uses for saving meta boxes (or custom fields), which you can [find here on GitHub](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/0b5ca2239f012e676d70d5011f9f96c503cc8220/packages/edit-post/src/store/actions.js#L557-L583). It basically uses [`wp.data.subscribe()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-data/#subscribe) to listen to changes in the editor's state (e.g. whether the editor is saving or autosaving the current post) and after the post is saved (but **not** autosaved), the meta boxes will be saved.

As for the PHP part, you can just store the error in a cookie and read its value using the [`window.wpCookies` API](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.1.1/src/js/_enqueues/lib/cookies.js#L10), which is a custom JavaScript cookie API written by WordPress.

So for example, I used the following when testing:

- PHP: `setcookie( 'event8273_add_notice', 'ERROR: A test error ' . time(), 0, '/' );`
- JS: `wpCookies.get( 'event8273_add_notice' )`

And for checking for and displaying the error, I used this:

```js
( () => {
    const editor = wp.data.select( 'core/editor' );

    // Name of the cookie which contains the error message.
    const cookieName = 'event8273_add_notice';

    // Set the initial state.
    let wasSavingPost     = editor.isSavingPost();
    let wasAutosavingPost = editor.isAutosavingPost();

    wp.data.subscribe( () => {
        const isSavingPost     = editor.isSavingPost();
        const isAutosavingPost = editor.isAutosavingPost();

        // Display the error on save completion, except for autosaves.
        const shouldDisplayNotice =
            wasSavingPost &&
            ! wasAutosavingPost &&
            ! isSavingPost &&
            // If its status is draft, then maybe there was an error.
            ( 'draft' === editor.getEditedPostAttribute( 'status' ) );

        // Save current state for next inspection.
        wasSavingPost     = isSavingPost;
        wasAutosavingPost = isAutosavingPost;

        if ( shouldDisplayNotice ) {
            const error = wpCookies.get( cookieName );

            // If there was an error, display it as a notice, and then remove
            // the cookie.
            if ( error ) {
                event_save_alert( error );
                wpCookies.remove( cookieName, '/' );
            }
        }
    } );
} )();
```

So just copy that and paste it into your JS file, after your custom `event_save_alert()` function.

- Make sure that the script's dependencies contain `wp-data`, `utils` *and* `wp-edit-post`.
- You should also load the script only on the post editing screen for your post type. E.g.

  ```php
  add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', function () {
      if ( is_admin() && 'event' === get_current_screen()->id ) {
          wp_enqueue_script(
              'your-handle',
              plugins_url( 'path/to/file.js', __FILE__ ),
              array( 'wp-data', 'utils', 'wp-edit-post' )
          );
      }
  } );
  ```

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: Glad to hear that :) and I should add that when setting the cookie, you might want to do it like so: `if ( defined( 'REST_REQUEST' ) && REST_REQUEST ) { setcookie( ... ); }`. Because Gutenberg uses the REST API.

Answer (score 0):

Since the notice is not a regular one, making a custom javascript notice would be easier. For simplicity, I use the alert() method to show it.

/location/our_custom_script.js:

```js
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
    
if urlParams.get('message') == 99 {
    alert("Wrong Meta!"); //or anything else
}
```

Then we use [enqueue_block_editor_assets](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/enqueue_block_editor_assets/) hook:

```php
function our_custom_error() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'our_custom_error',
        plugins_url('/location/our_custom_scripts.js', __FILE__)
    );
}
add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'our_custom_error');
```

It's not pretty, but it works, I hope...

ps: To make it similar to the real deal, I guess we can copy the original notice style. But I personally would style this kind of error in different manner than the usual notice.

Comment: The code only seems to trigger during the initial page load. I have placed a simple alert in the javascript file which is triggered only on initially, not during the post insertion.

Comment: I just realized nowadays Wordpress use its REST API, which happens after the page is generated and executed by browser via javascript. Thus, all those hooks are unusable.

When I have time, I would try to venture the solution, perhaps soon.

Comment: Thanks. You can check Sally CJ's working answer here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/413949/display-notice-in-block-editor-after-wp-insert-post-data-hook/413967#413967